# ::after pseudo element appearing before

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create a subtle wave on the top and bottom of a gradient. However, the ::after pseudo element is appearing before the main content and not after. Currently it's showing as ::before, ::after, main content, but I want it to show as ::before, main content, ::after.

Here's my code:

```css
#gradient {
  background: #0068a9;/* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Opera 11.1-12*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Fx 3.6-15*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Standard*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 0px;
  display: block;
}

#gradient::before,
#gradient::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

#gradient::before {
  background: #f2f2f2 url("http://www.qumidesignco.com/clients/preparedcapital/pc_topcurve.png") center top;
}

#gradient::after {
  background: #f2f2f2 url("http://www.qumidesignco.com/clients/preparedcapital/pc_bottomcurve.png") center top;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:#f2f2f2; width: 100%; height: 300px; min-height: 0px; display:block;"></div>
<div id="gradient"></div>
<div style="background:#f2f2f2; width: 100%; height: 300px; min-height: 0px; display:block;"></div>
```

Comment: `#gradient` has no content for the pseudo element to come after. Are you aware that `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements are positioned _inside_ the element?

Comment: what are you referring as "main content"?

Comment: Yup, I'm aware the pseudo elements are inside the element. I thought my height of 300px on #gradient would suffice. Is there a workaround to get the after element to display after the #gradient height?

Comment: Main content is the div #gradient. Having the after pseudo element appear after the #gradient height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `gradient div` `relative` , `:before and :after` `absolute` and `top:0` in `:before` and `bottom:0` in `:after`

```css
#gradient {
  background: #0068a9;/* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Opera 11.1-12*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Fx 3.6-15*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Standard*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  min-height: 0px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

#gradient::before,
#gradient::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  position: absolute;
}

#gradient::before {
  background: #f2f2f2 url("http://www.qumidesignco.com/clients/preparedcapital/pc_topcurve.png") center top;
  top:0;
}

#gradient::after {
  background: #f2f2f2 url("http://www.qumidesignco.com/clients/preparedcapital/pc_bottomcurve.png") center top;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:#f2f2f2; width: 100%; height: 300px; min-height: 0px; display:block;"></div>
<div id="gradient"></div>
<div style="background:#f2f2f2; width: 100%; height: 300px; min-height: 0px; display:block;"></div>
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It is appearing after normally. The problem is your div height. 
I added backgrounds to show where they are. Red is before and green is after

```css
#gradient {
  background: #0068a9;/* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Opera 11.1-12*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Fx 3.6-15*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 104, 169, 1), rgba(0, 104, 169, .9));/*Standard*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  min-height: 0px;
  display: block;
}

#gradient::before,
#gradient::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}

#gradient::before {
  background: #f2f2f2 url("http://www.qumidesignco.com/clients/preparedcapital/pc_topcurve.png") center top;
background-color: red;
}

#gradient::after {
  background: #f2f2f2 url("http://www.qumidesignco.com/clients/preparedcapital/pc_bottomcurve.png") center top;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:#f2f2f2; width: 100%; height: 300px; min-height: 0px; display:block;"></div>
<div id="gradient"></div>
<div style="background:#f2f2f2; width: 100%; height: 300px; min-height: 0px; display:block;"></div>
```