# Absolutely positioned pseudo after element is appearing before the rest of the content in the DOM

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've recently discovered the use of pseudo elements as graphical elements for design purposes. I'm trying to use a `::after` element on a div to create horizontal dividers between sections, below:

```css
.banner {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;

}
 .banner__text, .banner__logo {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
}
 .banner::after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="banner__text">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
      <p>longer string here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner__logo">
      <img src="//unsplash.it/159/250" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="banner">
    <div class="banner__text">
      <h3>Hello World</h3>
      <p>longer string here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="banner__logo">
      <img src="//unsplash.it/159/250" />
    </div>
  </div>

 <div class="banner">
   <div class="banner__text">
     <h3>Hello World</h3>
     <p>longer string here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="banner__logo">
     <img src="//unsplash.it/159/250" />
   </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

However, you will notice that all the `::after` elements stack right up at the top; is there a way I can have these absolutely positioned elements **that have relatively positioned parents** come *after* each `div.banner`?

Note: this question [::after pseudo element appearing before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343113/after-pseudo-element-appearing-before) has such a specific answer I cannot determine the solution, although it is similar in scope...

**UPDATE**

Adding `overflow: hidden` to `.banner` fixes the after elements stacking up at the top, but they still appear *before* the rest of the content in each `div.banner`, while I'd like them *after*.

Comment: close your div correctly

Comment: What is `left: 0; right: 0;`?

Comment: @Spectric that keeps it full (document) width

Comment: @TemaniAfif I edited the question, as you can see the issue still persists

Comment: overflow: hidden; to banner

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/8554043/8620333

Comment: I disagree, my question had a specific problem which needed to be solved, while that answer seems to go over the theory of what clearfix is and why/when to use it. I'd argue that it is a _related_ question as, while clearfix is _a_ solution to my problem, my question itself duplicated nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `bottom: 0` to make the dividers appear at the bottom of each `.banner`. For simplicity you'll probably want to use a bottom border instead of an `::after` pseudo-element for this, however. Not everything needs to be done with one. Having said that, there is nothing wrong with experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to add `overflow: hidden;` to `div.banner`, per [@Temani Afif's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) comment.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/wswiser101/pen/VwbrymZ)

#### EDIT

###### Additional Reading

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8554043/8620333) for a detailed description of why this failed, what clearfix is, and how this is conventionally solved.